# Not able to Download a file using RESTEasy Web Service - from Java HTTPClient not the browser

Tags: web-services, rest

I have searched for solution but no luck so far!

**Requirement:**
I am having a requirement to download a file eg., sample.jpg from a file system mount and the request has to be invoked from my project application. So, i built a webservice to do it and it's working fine if i call the web service directly on the browser. i.e., if i call the service through browser URL like below, the file is downloaded in my system's browser default download location.

Eg:http://localhost:8080/appname/rest/downloadservice/images

**WebService code:**

```
@Path("/downloadservice")
public class DownloadFileWS {

    @POST
    @Path("/images")   
    @Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})
    public Response getImageFile() { 
        /String FILE_PATH = "/ngs/app/sample.png";

        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);    
        Logger.getLogger("!!!!!!!!!!!"+FILE_PATH);  
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@"+FILE_PATH);
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);  

        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"sample.png\""); 
        return response.build();  
    }
```

So, here my browser acts as a client and it retrieves the file downloaded successfully.

Because there is a security concerns in calling the webservice directly through browser URL, i need to call this above webservice through my application java code (which is not exposed to the end user). So, in my project application java code, i built the HTTPClient and call the web service as below.

**Client code:**

```
public void getFileDownload(){  
        log("inside getServerPath....");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(downloadWebService_URL);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("filePath", "/ngs/app/sample.png");
        json.put("fileName", "sample.png");

        log("json-->"+json.toString());

        StringEntity inputJson = null;
        try {
            inputJson = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        log("inputJson = " + inputJson.toString());

        inputJson.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(inputJson);
        httpPost.addHeader("AppType", "TC");

        log("httpPost... httpPost");
        HttpResponse response = null; 
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            log("response:-->"+response);
            log("response.getEntity()-->"+response.getEntity());
            log("response.getEntity().getContent()-->"+response.getEntity().getContent());


            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.png\"");

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            log("111");
            String filePath = "sample.txt";
            log("222"); 
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            log("333"); 
            int inByte;
            while((inByte = is.read()) != -1){
                 fos.write(inByte);
                 log("444");
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();

            log("completed...");
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            log("E:: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

when i click on a image link in my application, i am triggering my above said client java code (getFileDownload() method) which in turn calls the web service using DefaultHttpClient.

**Question 1:**
Client java code is making call to the web service and my above web service is returning the response as below,

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 21:47:42 GMT, Content-Length:
>   6192, Content-Type: image/jpeg, Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="sample.png", X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1]
>   org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@35ae84bf

WebService returns the response as file download but since my HTTPClient java code receives the response, i am not sure how to use this HTTPResponse received from my webservice similar to **download the file in a browser.** The file is not downloaded if i click a link in my application, though the request and response communication happen as mentioned above.

**Question 2:**

Is there any way at the client side java code, we can achieve the file downloading after we get the response form the WebService HTTPResponse object?

**Question 3:**

Shall i change my approach as given below link?

> [Upload/Download File using REST or Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224275/upload-download-file-using-rest-or-web-services)

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any comments on this question please?